# Pyodbc can create/alter tables, but I can't see them in SSMS

Tags: python, sql-server, ssms, pyodbc

Pyodbc is correctly connecting to the same db. When I run

`SELECT name FROM sys.databases;`

`SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases;`

I get the list of all the DBs I can see in MSSQLSMS.

When I look at my Event Profiler in SSMS, I can see that Pyodbc is executing code actions on the same database in the same server as I look at with SSMS. I see my create table statements, select statements, that I'm running in Python with Pyodbc, executing on my SQL server.

So why can I not see the tables I've created in SSMS? Why, when I run the same queries in SSMS, do I not see the table I've created using Pyodbc?

I am extremely confused. Pyodbc appears to be connecting to my local SQL server correctly, and executing SQL code on it, but I'm not able to view the results using SSMS. I can find the table with Pyodbc, and Pyodbc and SSMS are both telling me they're looking at the same places, but SSMS can't see anything Pyodbc has done.

EDIT : Solved

`conn.autocommit=True` is required for Pyodbc to make permanent changes.

Comment: Two thoughts. A) You might need to refresh intellisense and 2) your login is different than the one in your code--one has access to the tables and one does not. I'd start there.

Comment: I do not know what Intellisense is. 

Re my login :

```('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                      'Server=servername;'
                      'Database=dbname;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=Yes')```

Is the format of my connection. Pyodbc MUST have access to the tables, because when I run select * from statements on tables I create with it (on the server!), it displays their contents correctly. Shouldn't SSMS always have access to everything given I'm logging in with windows auth as the only admin and user?

Comment: Are you sure it's the same instance of SQL Server? You can have multiple running on the same computer. Intellisense is the tool that does all the pop up suggestion stuff in SSMS (and other programs). I was thinking it may just be an issue with you needing to refresh the cache before you can see the tables. Restarting SSMS has the same effect.

Comment: Tried re-starting SSMS, no change. To my knowledge, I only have one instance of SQL server running on this computer, Pyodbc can only connect to an instance I'm running - does it create instances if none of the named instance exists?

Comment: If you are not setting `autocommit=True` then are you remembering to `.commit()` your changes?

Comment: Gord, this was it. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server allows some DDL statements (e.g., `CREATE TABLE`) to be executed inside a transaction. Therefore we also have to remember to `commit()` those changes if we haven't specified `autocommit=True` on the Connection.